# Keycloak - Microsoft Edge prevents successful authentication with 'keycloak-connect'

Tags: microsoft-edge, keycloak, jboss-tools

When using the Node.js adapter [keycloak-connect](https://www.npmjs.com/package/keycloak-connect) to protect a resource, the Microsoft Edge browser (v42+, Windows 10) prevents successful authentication.

This can be consistently replicated (but is not limited to) the following versions of Keycloak server and both respective versions of the client and server side adapters:

- 3.4.3
- 4.0.0
- 4.3.0
- 4.5.0

**What happens?**

Before the user is redirected from the authentication page and upon successful sign-in, the login success callback is instantiated twice. This second callback returns a '400' bad request before the redirect commences.

**To replicate:**

1. Open Microsoft Edge
2. Open the developer tools > Network tab and ensure the logs are not cleared on navigate.
3. Visit any page secured by Keycloak with no existing / active authentication session with the Microsoft Edge browser.
4. Enter your credentials and login.
5. You'll now see the error before redirect.

Typically this doesn't cause major issues with the client-side 'keycloak-js' library. But with any vanilla or custom implementation of the node adapter we try, because the authentication was successful and the redirect takes place, the web resources will load but immediately the callback takes place for a third time, giving a 403.

It then leaves the user in a semi-authenticated state and means the Node.JS server doesn't have access to the `kauth.grant` object, so subsequent secured requests to APIs have no access to the token server-side.

During the event keycloak server returns the following logs on this event:

```
WARN  [org.keycloak.services.managers.CodeGenerateUtil] (default task-17) Code '1122279c-b648-4ee5-b39e-9ea7b661126d' already used for userSession 'd1188910-d3f4-4dbc-bf06-ad96c2c96002' and client '934cb774-b345-477c-944a-b6b694f131e0'.

WARN  [org.keycloak.events] (default task-17) type=CODE_TO_TOKEN_ERROR, realmId=master, clientId=platform2, userId=null, ipAddress=172.18.0.1, error=invalid_code, grant_type=authorization_code, code_id=d1188910-d3f4-4dbc-bf06-ad96c2c96002, client_auth_method=client-secret
```

I'm raising this here on StackOverflow as per the JBoss developer guidelines, as technically this is an issue with Microsoft Edge.

It is incredibly important though as I believe many more people must be experiencing something related and unfortunately Edge has a large sized browser market share.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I am not available with any page which is secured by Keycloak. Can you provide any link, which we can use to test the issue on our side?

Comment: @RR-User, I’m seeing the same problem, but only for one user with Edge v17 and another user with Firefox v60. Unfortunately I can not reproduce it myself. Where you able to do that, or even find a cause / solution?